# oauth_signature does not match expected value

Tags: ios, oauth, tumblr

I'm using below link for my app for getting oauth_token and oauth_token_secret, but when i enter this link in chrome search bar, it gives me that error.

> oauth_signature does not match expected value.

Anyone know how we can create signature for oauth.

*`https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http://iosappsstore.com&oauth_consumer_key=SpFweFQePdB1I6GnbX2TKCrnD8sObObExERLtw1RBcaEZPFV26&oauth_nonce=4CDF1789&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=1514965684&oauth_signature=RJ0gX0kznCzgumfWjEvrxMDxWA=`*

Comment: How it is related with `swift` ? it shouldn't related even `objective-c` & `iOS`

Comment: @NazmulHasan i'm working with tumblr api on iOS

Comment: you  didn't pass the `request_token` secret to the request for access `token`

Comment: @NazmulHasan i dont have request_token. Can you explain?

Comment: I have only consumerKey and consumerSecret